# Firebase authentication - fix country

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

We are using firebase  mobile authentication in ionic application. We have set default country code to 'IN' the setting.
below is the code:

```
 signInOptions: [
        {
          provider: firebase.....,
          defaultCountry: 'IN',
        },
      ],
```

Now, we want to fix the country country code to 'IN' (User should not be able to change).
Please suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to set a fixed the country in FirebaseUI.

It is an [open-source library](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/#configuration) though, so could consider forking it and adding that feature yourself. You could even then submit a PR back to the main repo, which I'm quite sure would be appreciated.